# chronometer for counting seconds

Tags: java, android

I got this code from a website for chronometer  i want to run the chronometer when my activity starts and i want to recive the time running in seconds in a integer value  like

```
          myclock =  mChronometer.get vaule (example idea);
```

or anyother methods that can get value from chronometer directly

```
 import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.SystemClock;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.Chronometer;

  public class StopWatch extends Activity {
Chronometer mChronometer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button;

    mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    // Watch for button clicks.
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    button.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    button.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    button.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);

}

View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mChronometer.start();
    }
};

View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mChronometer.stop();
    }
};

View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    }
};
}
```

Thank u all in advance for helping me 
here is the link to the orginal site    http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/stop-watch-example/

Comment: Anu, see [Extending Android’s Chronometer to get Elapsed Time](http://craiget.com/extending-androids-chronometer-to-get-elapsed-time/) may help you in solving issue

Comment: ok seeing the example u gave

Comment: yes i am using the code atm trying to add to my another class once i finish i will post :)

Comment: `public void setMsElapsed(int ms) {
      setBase(getBase() - ms);
      msElapsed  = ms;
       }`   is  this the code to get the time passed from the activity started ?